# Can build, but can't run C code in netbeans (but it works in command line)

Tags: netbeans, exit

when I try Building the .exe of my code in C inside NB it makes it successful, but when I try to run it inside the program I always get this error:

```
Unable to start pty process: 
RUN FAILED (exit value -2, total time: 31ms)
```

But when I go inside the Run proprieties of the project and set the "Console Type" parameter to "External Terminal" it runs in the command line OK.

Any idea about what it could be? I am working with cygwin.

Comment: Me too. I have installed Netbeans 7.3.1 and installed cygwin. The same error

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I fixed the problem going to Properties Project -> Run -> Console Type -> External Terminal. In this way you can compile using Netbeans.

Comment: It was a pleasure help all you :-)

Comment: I was having the same problem but with different exit value (-1,073,741,790) but your answer helped my problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on netbeans change to standard output your console, that work for me. Do as follow:
Properties Project -> Run -> Console Type ->standard output