# Netbeans C/C not compiling

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, cygwin

I installed the **NetBeans** IDE 7.3.1 almost a week ago and still haven't been able to get it to compile anything.
I'm using the **Cygwin**'s compiler for C/C++, and I get the following error message for a simple *"Hello World"* program:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/CaptFuzzyboots/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello World'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/hello_world.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/CaptFuzzyboots/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello World'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o.d
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o main.c
make[2]: gcc: Command not found
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target `build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/CaptFuzzyboots/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello World'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target `.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/CaptFuzzyboots/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello World'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target `.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 472ms)
```

---

### EDIT

**I fixed this** by just making a new toolkit and adding the base directory as  Cygwin -> bin.

The problem now is that I keep getting

> Unable to start pty process

Comment: `gcc: Command not found `, sounds like your cygwin installation might not have all the needed tools. Did you check the tools listed [here](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/cpp-setup-instructions.html#cygwin)?

Comment: madth3 - I got all of them :)
Still don't know why
I got the C compiler,Debugger,C++ compiler and the make utility

Answer (score 2):

### `gcc: Command not found`

1. You should check whether you have installed `gcc` (plus `gdb` and `make`)

   1. via [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/):

      [MinGW+NetBeans](https://wiki.sch.bme.hu/Sz%C3%A1m%C3%ADt%C3%B3g%C3%A9pes_grafika:_OpenGL_+_GLUT_+_fejleszt%C5%91k%C3%B6rnyezetek#NetBeans_.28Windows.29) (just look at the screenshots, you don't have to understand Hungarian)

      [image: MinGW Compiler Suite]

      [image: MinGW Installation Manager]
   2. via [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/):

      http://www.eecg.utoronto.ca/~aamodt/ece242/cygwin.html

      [image: Cygwin, gcc, gdb, make]
2. You should also check whether paths are correct in NetBeans:

   Tools > Options > C/C++ > **Build Tools**:

   (At the time of creating the screenshot, I had MinGW installed in `C:\Programs\MinGW`, BUT if you have it installed in `C:\MinGW` (which is the default), this correct, too! The only important thing is that you should install MinGW in a path which doesn't contain whitespaces.)

   [image: NetBeans: Tools > Options > C/C++ > Build Tools]

   This is what it looks like when paths are incorrect, letters are red:

   [image: NetBeans: Tools > Options > C/C++ > Build Tools, incorrect paths]

   Note: I have MinGW installed, but it doesn't change the fact that you should check whether YOUR paths are correct.
3. You should also take care the right Configuration is selected in project Properties (right click on project) > Build - The right "Tool collection" has to be selected (on which the paths above are correct):

   [image: NetBeans: project properties > Build > Tool collection]

### `Unable to start pty process`

Related answer: [Can build, but can't run C code in netbeans (but it works in command line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049467/can-build-but-cant-run-c-code-in-netbeans-but-it-works-in-command-line/18098515#18098515)

So right click on the project, Properties > Run > Console Type > **External Terminal** (instead of e.g. "Internal Terminal"). Here is a screenshot:

[image: NetBeans: project, Properties > Run > Console Type > External Terminal]

Comment: It also works with Standard output. In my case it worked.

Comment: @rammayur: it was a long time ago, I can't test it now, but I wrote the last advice (changing the Console Type) to the OP's _"Unable to start pty process"_ error message - I don't remember why it didn't work with Standard Output, but setting it to External Terminal solved the problem then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
gcc: Command not found
```

Cygwin is not a compiler, it's a unix-like environment for Windows. Gcc is the compiler. You have to install gcc with Cygwin before it will work.

Comment: Yes,I installed the gcc g++ and c compiler from the cygwin installation menu,but if you say so,I shall try again :)
Thanks