# Unable to start pty process:

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile, cygwin

When I build my code in C++ using NetBeans.

```
"make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
 make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Alex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/test'
"make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/test.exe
 make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Alex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/test'
 make[2]: 'dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/test.exe' is up to date.
 make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Alex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/test'
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Alex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/test'
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 652ms)
```

When I run my code in C++ using NetBeans...

```
 Unable to start pty process: 
 RUN FAILED (exit value -2, total time: 26ms)
```

My Code

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
 cout << "Hello, World!\n";
 return 0;
 }
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: Likely, that's not the problem with your code, but rather with the environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can build, but can't run C code in netbeans (but it works in command line)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049467/can-build-but-cant-run-c-code-in-netbeans-but-it-works-in-command-line)

Answer (score 9):

Worked solution for me : 
Netbeans :
 File-> Project properties -> Run -> Console type -> External Terminal

Comment: In Netbeans 8.2 'Project properties' are accessed by Right clicking the project

Answer (score 2):

here's the corresponding Netbeans bug https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=234221 People tell that the "use of external terminal" option may help

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the run compiler under project properties - run from c++ (what it says actually) to g++. Plus the "external terminal" it worked.